# Getting view of DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I have created Dialog Fragment with custom layout and want to set text for some textboxes. But when trying to get view in my adapter image click I'm getting null pointer exception.

I would like to know is there any best way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private View dialogView;
    private static IDialogButtonsClicks buttonsClicks;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

    public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title, int icon, int positive, int negative, int view, int message, IDialogButtonsClicks clicks)
    {
        AlertDialogFragment dialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        args.putInt("icon", icon);
        args.putInt("pos", positive);
        args.putInt("neg", negative);
        args.putInt("view", view);
        args.putInt("message", message);

        buttonsClicks = clicks;

        dialogFragment.setArguments(args);

        return dialogFragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        int dView = getArguments().getInt("view");
        int mess = getArguments().getInt("message");

        if (dView != -1)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(dView, null);

            alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
        }

        if (mess != -1)
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage(mess);
        }

        alertDialog.setTitle(getArguments().getInt("title"));
        alertDialog.setIcon(getArguments().getInt("icon"));

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getArguments().getInt("pos"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                buttonsClicks.OnPositiveButtonClick(dialogView);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getArguments().getInt("neg"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                buttonsClicks.OnNegativeButtonClick();
            }
        });

        return alertDialog.create();
    }

    public View getDialogView()
    {
        return dialogView;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView()
    {
        return super.getView();
    }
}



holder.imgCatEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                AlertDialogFragment editCatDialog = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.add_category_title, R.drawable.ic_edit, R.string.edit_cat_button_save, R.string.edit_cat_button_cancel, R.layout.edit_category, -1, new IDialogButtonsClicks()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void OnPositiveButtonClick(View view)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void OnNegativeButtonClick()
                    {

                    }
                });

                editCatDialog.show(((MyBusinessMainActivity)baseContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "EditCatDialog");

                View dialogView = editCatDialog.getView();//It seems here I'm getting null

                EditText ed_edit_cat_name = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ed_edit_cat_name);
                EditText ed_edit_cat_descr = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ed_edit_cat_descr);

                ed_edit_cat_name.setText(cat_name);
                ed_edit_cat_descr.setText(cat_descr);
            }
        });





11-23 12:40:49.708 19702-19702/am.nkr.mybusiness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: am.nkr.mybusiness, PID: 19702
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at am.nkr.mybusiness.CategoriesAdapter$2.onClick(CategoriesAdapter.java:165)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when you do `editCatDialog.getView();` the view have not been yet initializied (`onCreateDialog()` was not called).

The best way would be to add listeners in dialog in `onViewCreated` method. Then passing those events to your main fragment (e.g. via `buttonClicks` variable).

If you want to make it in a quick and hacky way you could write `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransaction()` after `show` method

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Is it normal to use hacky way?

Comment: It is hacky way, because dialog is a component when view was created and so dialog should set listener on it views. With this you would have independent dialog component that can be reusable in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you got that error because when you call `ed_edit_cat_name.setText(cat_name);`, your `DialogFragment` callback `onCreateView` is not finished! To overcome this problem, I think you can declare some variables to hold your `cat_name` and `cat_des` in your `DialogFragment` as below:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
     private String catName;// getter - setter 
     private String catDes;//getter-setter
     // TODO: find your view and set cat name, description in onCreateView callback.
}
```

Then, you can set your cat name, cat des when you create new instance of `DialogFragment`.

Comment: It's also the way to do it. Thanks.